# Optimizing nginx with SSL for bot traffic without sessions

Tags: nginx, ssl, optimization, high-load

The service I run, cronitor.io, has a telemetry collection API that sees bursts of traffic around 1000rps. (overall baseline is much lower, call it 100rps)

Most of our requests come from things like curl and the most popular HTTP libraries in each language (Requests, Guzzle, etc). These clients do not maintain an SSL session the way a browser would. This results in a lot of SSL handshakes for comparatively small http requests.

I would love any tips on optimizing nginx for this use case. We upstream requests to uwsgi. Relevant portion from current nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
client_max_body_size 20M;
gzip on;
```

This was essentially cloned from our app servers. I've done some research and I have some ideas on things to try (disabling server tokens, for example) but I would love any advice.

Comment: Caching. And don't use ancient CPUs.

Comment: This is a data collection API, nothing to cache. Using m4.larges on AWS currently.

Comment: So where is your bottleneck? Even without SSL session resumption and other such tricks, it shouldn't be a significant amount of CPU.